# Python how to remove the trailing new_line character when writting in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, file, file-handling

So I have a string that I want to write in a file.
I am 100% sure that the string has no trailing `\n` or newline or anything like that.
But still, when I try to write it into a file it adds a new line to the file at the, and I do not understand why.
I need to have the last line of the file without the automatically added `\n`.
Do you know how can I do this?

sample of written file: [image: sample of written file]

The writing code (the matrix always has 9 rows and 9 columns):

```py
output = ""
index = 0
for each_line in structure_matrix:
    for each_tile in each_line:
        output += str(each_tile)
    index += 1
    if index % 3 == 0 and index != 9:
        output += "\n"
        index = 0
file_to_write_in_predictions.write(output)
```

Thanks!

Comment: the last index is `8`, right?

Comment: yes, it is. when the var index reaches 9 it means that the last line has been added to the output.

Comment: You could just remove the very last '\n' from `output` when writing the file by calling `output.strip()`

Comment: Tried that already, it will still add the '/n' at the end. It's like it automatically adds it when writing to the file.

Comment: Try reading the file in again using python and printing it. Maybe Notepad is adding the line at the end.

Comment: @RaresG `file.write()` does not add newline characters

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do. I would create a new list composed of the lines you created while using your data and then inside "with" statement I would create a logic that writes each item from the list to a txt file and unless its the last one it adds a new line to it.
I tested it for the following data and it seems to work

```py
some_data_c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
some_data_r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
output = ""
new_row = []
for c in some_data_c:
    for r in some_data_r:
        output += str(r)    
    new_row.append(output)
    output = ""
print(new_row)
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(len(new_row)):
        print(i)
        if i < (len(new_row)-1):
            f.write(new_row[i]+"\n")
        else:
            f.write(new_row[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you reset `index` to 0 every time it is a multiple of 3, it will never reach 9 and the condition `if index % 3 == 0 and index != 9` will be true for the 9th line as well. Removing `index = 0` should do the trick.